# Strange gap between two buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with the HTML `button` tag. It seems that when I place two buttons side by side, they have a `4px` gap between them appearing out of nowhere.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ov16yxb7/) which shows the issue.

As you can see from the image below, FireBug shows that the gap is neither a `margin` or a `padding` (since a `padding` would be shown in purple).

[image]

As a note: I'm using the latest version of Firefox on Windows 8.1 and I tried also with the CSS Reset from Eric Mayer, but the gap is still there.

It's not a really important problem, but it would be nice to know if it's normal or not and what causes it.

Comment: It's because whitespace. set parent's font-size:0 to get rid of issue! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ov16yxb7/9/ check it's done :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that in `inline-block` elements the whitespace in HTML becomes visual space on screen. Some solutions to fix it:

1. Use `font-size: 0` to parent container(you have to define font-size to child elements):

```css
.buttons {
  width: 304px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
}
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid dimgray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

2. Another one is to use negative `margin-left: -4px`

```css
.buttons {
  width: 304px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid dimgray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

3. Last but i don't like it at all is to use html comments as spacers
   between gaps:

```css
.buttons {
  width: 304px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid dimgray;
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>Button1</button><!--
 --><button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

All above will work. Good luck :)

Answer (score 9):

It's because you have whitespace between `button` elements. Change your HTML to:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ov16yxb7/5/)

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Button1</button><button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

---

If you just want to display one line between these `button`s, add `margin: -1px`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ov16yxb7/11/)

```
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid dimgray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

#### Additional Tweaks:

In Firefox, when you click on a button, it displays a weird dotted border like below:

[image]

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ov16yxb7/13/)

To get rid of this, add this to your CSS:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

---

One more thing(Firefox): when you click on the button, the text moves. To prevent this add this to your CSS:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ov16yxb7/12/)

```
button:active {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just that simple? But I want to keep them indented. It does not make a lot of sense. But being them `inline` elements maybe it does...

Answer (score 2):

It can be corrected by

```
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid dimgray;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it is the whitespace between your elements. If you're using PHP, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Button1</button><?php
    ?><button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could do this:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Button1</button><
     button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

Or this, as suggested from the comments:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>Button1</button><!--
    --><button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Otherwise, you could use html comments.

Comment: You're right! I updated my post to reflect that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

if you `float: right;` or `float: left;` you will see no space.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ov16yxb7/2/)

Comment: see http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF